# Error accessing C# web app from other machine on my LAN

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

When I try to reach my asp web app in C:/intpub/wwwroot/ by accessing the URL

`http://ipaddress/mywebsite/loginpage.aspx`

a Compilation Error occurs with this description:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'DataManager' does not exist
>   in the current context

When I open and debug or browse it with vs2010 this error doesn't appear.

**note**: *Datamanager.cs* is a class in App_Code I use to write ADO code.

This is the source of the error:

```
void LogIn(string username, string password)
{
int count = (int)DataManager.ExecuteScalar("user_check", CommandType.StoredProcedure,
DataManager.CreateParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, username)
, DataManager.CreateParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, password));
```

Comment: `http://localhost/mywebsite/loginpage.aspx` could help

What kind of `ipaddress` have you written?

Comment: When you debug using Visual Studio what is the url that is used to access the site (e.g. what is in the browsers address bar)?

Comment: and i checked existence of the Datamanager.cs in App_Code and it is already exists

Comment: i fixed my ip to 10.5.50.10

Comment: the url : http://localhost:8159/Store/loginpage.aspx

Comment: Please, validate if your are not debugging in the local web development server. Because your local URL seems that you have a port number, while the IIS one doesnt have.

Comment: well when i debug the web from vs i got this URL: "http://localhost:8159/Store/loginpage.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
void LogIn(string username, string password)
{
    DataManager dm = new DataManager();
    int count = (int)dm.ExecuteScalar("user_check", CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    DataManager.CreateParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, username),
        DataManager.CreateParameter("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, password));
}
```

Comment: I thik the problem is in deploying the web in my machine

Comment: and by the way this error occurs : Error 4 Member 'DataManager.ExecuteScalar(string, System.Data.CommandType, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[])' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Store\loginpage.aspx.cs 37 26 C:\...\Store\

Answer (score 0):

This can be a namespace or a class innitialization problem. Check if you have declared the namespace in your login.aspx for the DataManager class. Also check if you have declared the DataManager class inside a loop or a try/catch block.
[Compiler error CS0103-MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)